# How to approach contemporary anarchist theories?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, learning-methods, anarchism

I have lately become very interested in anarchism. I have become especially interested in what is called [Green Anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_anarchism) and [Infoanarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infoanarchism) and I pretend to read more about them. I also agree with queer, feminist and ethnic anarchism in almost all their main points.

Wikipedia has served me as an introduction to the subject but the quantity of information available is overwhelming. I have started to read "[Walden](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/205)" by Thoreau because it is considered by many as an early influence of Green Anarchism but I don't know exactly how to continue or contemporary authors in these topics.

**Are there any modern books appropriate to approach these schools of thought?**

I feel that although reading "classical" texts as the one by Thoreau might be very useful it is also necessary to read contemporary thinkers to understand the actual status of the topic and get to know what role these movements play in the modern world.

**What is the best way to approach such a broad subject as the study of anarchist schools of thought?**

P.S. I don't know if I should post this as two separate questions or even if this is on topic here (although I believe it to be so). If it is not the case please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Anarchists are defined by their stance towards society, so a good way to approach anarchist ideology is to acquire some understanding of society - what it is, how it 'works', what are power, property, rights, etc. Specific areas as ecology or information are seen to be more restricted cases.

In the study of society economics and politics take too much for granted, so I think the best approach is through cultural anthropology:  societies in which the uncle takes care of his sister's children, not the father, or societies in which gifts and prestige are more valuable than property and other 'strange' ways of  behaving have been documented. David Graeber's work is a really good place to begin:  *Toward an Anthropological Theory of Value: The False Coin of Our Own Dreams* (2001) оr *Fragments of an Anarchist Anthropology* (2004) readily come to mind here.